# Create sub Directories in Layout Res in Android

Tags: android

I'm working on app which is not simple. There are many modules so I want to manage them properly by creating sub directories. I try the structure below but still was not able to achieve this.

```
 res
     layout
          camera
                main.xml

 // Structure is like this
 // res-> layout -> camera -> main.xml
```

By Default all `xml` layout files are under `layout` folder. But I want to create another folder under layout folder with name **camera** like this `layout-> camera` and want to put `Activity` layout under this **camera** folder
like this `layout -> camera -> main.xml`. So, I did it and place may layout files under **camera** folder. But now There is a problem when I open `main.xml` , an error appears when you hover mouse on `xmlns:android` :

In **main.xml** :

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 // Error: URI is not register (Setting | language | framework Schems and DTDs
```

I think the reason of error is **changing path of layout files** . Because all files are under **layout** by default. And I changed the path. How can solve this error but remember I want my layout files under **camera** folder.

And there is another problem how can I access the sub folder of layout in `java` classes for example I have file named `main.xml` under `res->layout->camera` I tried the following code but there is error.

In **MainActivity** :

```
 setContentView(R.layout.camera.main);
 // Error: can not resolve symbol camera
```

How can I solve this and access the files from sub folders which are under **layout** folder.

I searched some Stackoverflow questions and found something but still this is not working.

**Gradle**

```
  sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs =
                [
                        'src/main/res/layouts/camera',
                        'src/main/res'
                ]
    }
}
```

Please let me know how I can solve this problem. I'm new in android.

Comment: Your question is not very clear on what is the problem about.

Comment: I'm not able to access `main.xml` file in Acticvity class and also not able to make design in `main.xml` check the question I define two errors. That's the problem for me

Comment: I write an answer below. Check it and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your `main.xml` and all of your layouts should be under res/layout because `layout` is the folder that holds all layouts of your app.

After you change that, go in **MainActivity** and use:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

In Gradle make this changes:

```
sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
```

and always when you change things in gradle, ALWAYS do sync!

I guess this should solve your problem.

Comment: No this is not solving. Problem still same

Comment: Did you move all your layouts under **res/layout** ?

Comment: I want to create sub directories under layout folder

Comment: Above your project files, you can switch to "Project View" instead of "Android View" and you can create sub folders under layout folder.

Comment: I know I already create but problem is that files under these folder work not perfectly. Can you please see my question again

Comment: I have read your question but still is not clear to me. Try to edit the question or explain in more clear way what exactly you are trying to achieve.